# Declare table as not replicable

Tags: sql-server, replication, merge-replication

How can I make sure that a certain table is not selected as an article in a publication? So that this table is never replicated (even by error).
The replication for the database is setup by different people and one particular table should never be included in the replication. Can we make that table non selectable in the publication wizard (the step where the articles are added to the publication) or is there any way we can use the database schema to define that this table is not available as article in a publication?

Type of replication used: merge replication

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I know to do that is to leverage this limitation:

> Tables published for transactional replication must have a primary
>   key.

[Publish Data and Database Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/publish/publish-data-and-database-objects?view=sql-server-2017)

So replace the table's primary key with a unique clustered index called `pk_MyTable_PreventReplication` or somesuch.

Merge replication requires a special ROWGUIDCOL column on the table, which you can prevent with security or a DDL trigger.

Comment: Thank you! this is a great hint, unfortunately the type of replication we use is merge-replication where this limitation doesn't seem to apply (I will update my question - I only had added this bit of information as a tag instead of text in my question - sorry). Is there any similar limitation for merge-replication that would prevent replication of a table?

Comment: See update to answer for merge Replication.